# Debugging puppet: how do I show the available modules in a manifest?

Tags: puppet

My context:

- I'm including a module which in turn includes more modules
- when I run a "puppet apply" the first included module runs fine...
- until it gets to the "include" statement for the other module
- the mechanism I'm using to include modules is nonstandard and is part of the infrastructure I'm working in.  Usually I could just check a directory and see if the module is there... but since there is "magic" involved in including modules, I have to debug during the apply.

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could  not find class *missingmoduleclassname*

My question:

- I'd like to print out the available modules to stdout during the apply.  Is there a way to do that?
- I'm already using code like:  `notify{"The list of modules available is: ${yourvar}": }`

  - **Is there a variable I can print out?  What is it called?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus seems to be: there isn't a way to easily do this!  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want are messages that are printed during the *compilation phase* of `puppet apply` (there is also a catalog application phase, but that is not reached here because compilation fails).

There are some [parser functions](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html) that allow that:

- notice
- warning
- err
- crit
- emerg

You could add this at the top of your `mymodule` class body:

```
notice "evaluating mymodule ..."
```

etc. for each individual module.

Comment: Thanks Felix.  I've got these and am basically "debugging with printf."  The part I'm missing is: what am I printing out inside the string?What is the thing that shows the modules that are available?

Comment: No, I disbelieve that. It would not make sense for the master to enumerate the modules before any of them is ever used. It will lookup modules on first use instead.

Comment: Felix, I'm not sure what you are expressing here.  You disbelieve... what?

Comment: Err yes. Sorry :) I don't think that such a variable or any method of querying this information is available.